# Generate MAKFILE dependency with header and source files in separate directory

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have 3 layer architecture project for embedded

`top layer      - application`

`middle layer - middle(HAL Layer)`

`bottom layer - bottom(Driver layer)`

I need to make a Makefile for the project with multiple source and header files which are in different directories.

For sake of understanding of makefile consider this as c project.

The issue I am facing is I am not able to generate the `dependency files` for the source files.

I have seen many tutorials but mostly in the example code of MAKEFILE, the header files are present in the same folder with the source files.

In my case the files are in the below structure.

```
project
|
|---- _build(DIR)
|     --- Makefile
|
|---- application(DIR) 
|                  inc/main.h
|                  src/main.c
|
|---- middle(DIR) 
|                 inc/middle.h
|                 src/middle.c
|
|---- bottom(DIR) 
|                 inc/bottom.h
|                 src/bottom.c
```

As the header files are in separate folder, I am not able to generate the dependency files(.d files).

Without including header files like

> -I<header_files>

How to generate the dependency files?

http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/

No Header file is included using -I options because source and header files are in same folder

Youtube example but same result, header and source in same folders.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NPdagdEOBnI

Comment: If the program used to generate the dependencies is GCC you should add that tag to the post.

Comment: You need `-I`-options even when using dependency files as the dependency files only track dependencies, not how headers are located from any source file. Could be located through `-I`-option, or it could be located relative the source file including the header.